# How to get a Struct's value inside a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct

Newbie programmer here!

I want to get nested structs' value inside a dictionary but I can't reach inside the dictionary.

This is my struct

```
struct Forecast: Decodable {
    let cod: String
    let message: Int
    let cnt: Int
    let list: [List]
    let city: City
}

struct List: Decodable {
    let dt: Int
    let main: Main
    let weather: [Weather]
    let clouds: Clouds
    let wind: Wind
    let sys: Sys
    let dt_txt: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, sys, dt_txt = "dt_txt"
    }
}

struct Main: Decodable {
    let temp: Double                           // I want to get this!
    let feels_like: Double
    let temp_min: Double
    let temp_max: Double
    let pressure: Int
    let sea_level: Int
    let grnd_level: Int
    let humidity: Int
    let temp_kf: Double
}
```

I tried to reach it as struct syntax but couldn't make it:

```
self.tempLbl.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list.main.temp)) - 273)°" 
// Value of type '[List]' has no member 'main'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my dumb question, I feel really bad for asking this..

I am able to reach my destination with this:

```
self.tempLbl.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list[1].main.temp)) - 273)°"
// weather.list[1].main.temp
```

Comment: Is that hard coded index really what you want? First index in an array is at 0 and not 1 and you would get a crash with your current code if list contains only one item or if it is empty